# Python 3d plot from directly 3 Arrays (two 1-D and one 2-D )

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please consider this code:

```
import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,2,3])            
z = np.array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25],
       [ 0,  2,  8, 18, 32, 50],
       [ 0,  3, 12, 27, 48, 75]])

plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d').plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='viridis')
```

This will return: `shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`.
If you google Python 3D plot for help mostly you will find how to plot from ***functions*** by generating data with `meshgrid`. However my question is. What is the easiest way to plot when you have an array?
The solution to this problem should look something like this:
[image]

For instance one point is `(x=3,y=2,z=18)`

Comment: Doesn't Matplotlib plot points, so this is really just a meshgrid but spaced out entirely too far?

Comment: I think you are right. And that's even more confusing to me that this will not work?

Comment: You find functions in most examples, simply because people are too lazy to type in a complete array. Matplotlib itself plots points. For `plot_surface` all input arrays must be 2D. That is shown in the existent examples, so closing this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the shapes for each axis. You can do this using [numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) which makes a mesh grid with x and y:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,2,3])
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # make a meshgrid out of x and y
z = np.array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25],
       [ 0,  2,  8, 18, 32, 50],
       [ 0,  3, 12, 27, 48, 75]])

plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d').plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

x after meshgrid:

```
 [[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]]
```

y after meshgrid:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3]]
```